# Merge getSymbols result into one xts object

Tags: r, quantmod

I have the following code:

```
library(quantmod)
tckrs <- c("TLT", "LQD", "HYG", "SPY", "DBC")
NumTckrs  <-  length(tckrs)
getSymbols(tckrs, from="1900-01-01", to=Sys.Date())

# merge to allign the start dates
MainDF <- merge(Ad(TLT), Ad(LQD), Ad(HYG), Ad(SPY), Ad(DBC), all=FALSE)
```

I would like to not have to repeat the stock symbols in the last line. Does anyone know how this could be done?

Answer (score 5):

Load all the data into an environment, then call `Ad` on each, and merge them.  Also note that `getSymbols` returns an xts object by default, therefore your `MainDF` is an xts object, not a data.frame.

```
library(quantmod)
# create new environment
myEnv <- new.env()
# pull all data and load into myEnv
getSymbols("TLT;LQD;HYG;SPY;DBC", env=myEnv)
# eapply calls Ad on each symbol in myEnv and returns a list
# do.call calls merge with each element returned from eapply as an argument
MainXTS <- do.call(merge, c(eapply(myEnv, Ad),all=FALSE))
```

Comment: Nice use of environment. Seems the getSymbols behavior is well suited for this approach.

Comment: plus 1: for using `eapply` alone!

Answer (score 3):

This is one line of code with my [qmao](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1113) package

```
library(qmao)
p <- makePriceFrame(tckrs, prefer='Adjusted', silent=TRUE)
```

For convenience, `PF` is an alias for `makePriceFrame`.  Also, since by default, the function will find and use the "Adjusted" column if it exists, you can leave out the `prefer` argument.

```
p <- PF(tckrs)
```

You can also combine a bunch of these types of functions

```
library(FinancialInstrument)
p <- PF(getSymbols(stock(tckrs, currency("USD"))))
```

Also, note that if you hadn't assigned your Symbol names to `tckrs`, you'd be able to get them from the PriceFrame.

```
names(p)
[1] "TLT" "LQD" "HYG" "SPY" "DBC"
```

If you do not specify a `prefer` argument, it looks for a column that contains "Adjusted", then "Close", then "Mid", then Price".  To see which column was used to make the PriceFrame, look at the "prefer" attribute

```
attr(p, "prefer")
[1] "Adjusted"
```

If you keep data in separate environments, `PF` can handle that as well.

```
getSymbols(tckrs, env=myEnv)
p <- PF(ls(myEnv), env=myEnv)
```

Comment: Will qmao ever find itself on CRAN, or is it eternally banished to R-Forge?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JoshuaUlrich. I guess it's about that time.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich it `Depends` on FinancialInstrument, soooo... maybe it is banished.  I think the main reason we've been putting off pushing FinancialInstrument to CRAN is because the package-level docs need polishing up.  I've also been hanging on to a sliver of hope that one day I'll have time to put currencies in their own environment, but I'm not sure anyone shares that hope ;-).  So, maybe it's time to just get them both on CRAN.

Comment: @cdcaveman, install the package, then type `help(package=qmao, help_type="html")`

Answer (score 2):

Joshua's is probably more elegant than mine:

```
res <- do.call( merge,  lapply(  lapply(tckrs, get) , Ad) )
```