# Manipulating multiple objects in R

Tags: r, quantmod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [r names of quantmod variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179154/r-names-of-quantmod-variables)
>   [R: merging a lot of data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096814/r-merging-a-lot-of-data-frames)

I would like to perform a function on several objects. I know I can use `merge()` for 2:

`library(quantmod)`
`symb <- c('AAPL', 'GE')`
`getSymbols(symb, from='2005-01-01')`
`foo <- merge(AAPL$AAPL.Adjusted, GE$GE.Adjusted)`

But let's say `symb` is all the constituents of the Dow Industrials; `getSymbols` returns 30 objects. I still want to end up with a table or xts of adjusted prices for all 30 stocks.

I can imagine a `merge` loop that would add each symbol's Adjusted column to the new object, but:

- This is inelegant. Is there a better way? Someone suggested `Reduce()`, but I couldn't make sense of it in this context.
- I don't know how to call each of the symbols that will appear in `objects()` anyway.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11179369/967840) is a common and safe way to do this with `getSymbols`

Comment: Related: [getSymbols and using lapply, Cl, and merge to extract close prices](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5574595/271616)